# make url in json clickable

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a huge JSON file which consist of different fields, some fields may contain a URL and I would like to make all URLs clickable. Is there a way to make all urls clickable without accessing the data through its field?

Here is a sample of my JSON file:

```
{
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "google",
          "desc": "this is google (https://www.google.com/) "
        },
        {
          "name": "yahoo",
          "url": "https://au.yahoo.com/"
        },
        {
          "name": "stackoverflow",
          "link": " click this, https://stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I guess your links will be appended to the DOM tree, so you can achieve this with `String#replace` and a regular expression. And which nested objects are you talking about?

Comment: "Clickable" is a quality that applies to something which is shown (rendered), and JSON can be rendered through a gazillion different ways, with half of these possible with a user agent (what the millennials call "the browser"). You have unfortunately left us guesstimating how you are rendering the quoted text. It's just data, in and out of itself. Without knowing how you're rendering it, no advice on how to make links clickable, will apply.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let r=d.example.map(x=> (x.u=x.url||x.link||x.desc, x))
               .map(x=> (x.u=x.u.match(/http[^ )(]*/),x))
               .map(x=> `<div><a href="${x.u}"> ${x.name}</a></div>`)

msg.innerHTML = r.join('')
```

W use here standard JS/HTML features [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [regexp match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [string join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [or operator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/82593/314529) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
let d={
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "google",
          "desc": "this is google (https://www.google.com/) "
        },
        {
          "name": "yahoo",
          "url": "https://au.yahoo.com/"
        },
        {
          "name": "stackoverflow",
          "link": " click this, https://stackoverflow.com"
        },
    ]
}

let r=d.example.map(x=> (x.u=x.url||x.link||x.desc, x))
               .map(x=> (x.u=x.u.match(/http[^ )(]*/),x))
               .map(x=> `<div><a href="${x.u}"> ${x.name}</a></div>`)
               
msg.innerHTML = r.join('')
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: You should add some notes to the code to explain what's going on otherwise it's just a code dump.